# Why does embedding code from an Outlook Calendar into a SharePoint page display different borders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

1. I went to Outlook and clicked on *Email Calendar*
2. I then selected a range of the next 7 days
3. For detail I selected *Full Detail*
4. I then sent it to myself
5. I opened the email and Viewed Source.
6. I went to my SP2013 site and copied the code into a Page (Insert/Embed Code)

SharePoint did a pretty good job of displaying it just like I found in my email, but the border lines do not display correctly between the Details section and the start of the details.  Any suggestions?  Everyone on my tems loves how Outlook gives a nice detail of the events thus the reason why I am trying to replicate the Outlook version of the Email calendar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CSS style is either missing, or being overriden in SharePoint by some SharePoint CSS style. View the page in browser DOM tools (F12), to see what style is affecting the borders.

You can even open the original email in browser (Actions --> View in Browser) to see what styles it applies to the borders and compare that to the styles that are applied when same HTML is within SharePoint.